# Why does play framework recompile every time I run a test?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

Working on a test is very slow because play compiles over 60 files every time I run "test", regardless of whether or not I've changed any files. Here are my steps:

1. Go into the play console
2. test:compile
3. test-only com.comp.ClassTester

The output I get from the test-only starts with:

```
[info] Compiling 67 Scala sources to /Users/bseraph/workspace/code/target/scala-2.10/classes...
```

It's making the testing process painfully slow as it takes 10-30 seconds to do this compile every time. Why does it do this?

I'm on play 2.2.1

Comment: Have to ask the obvious first. Are you modifying a class that is used by 60 other source files?

Comment: No. Note in my steps to reproduce I run the test compile BEFORE I run the test. It will do this compilation every time even if I have changed no files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that routes.conf is being generated and compiled every time you do any task. I did some research into the issue and it doesn't look like there is a way to turn that off for now.

Comment: That's really sad. When my project was really small That was no problem for me that. But now this is taking a lot of time!